# Why is "src/main/java" included in my package names in Sonar?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, cobertura

We have a Java (7) project that uses Maven (3.2.1). We have a Jenkins (1.554) server, and we use it to run code analysis with SonarQube (4.3).

I have configured the default dashboard to show a few treemaps to visualize the test coverage in different parts of the project (using the link Configure widgets -> Category: Filters -> the "Measure Filter as Treemap" widget). The code gets analyzed totally fine, the test coverage gets recorded, the diagrams are colorful and everything is good.

Almost. We are using standard Maven folders for the code, and the package names are in the format "com.ourdomain.someapplication.subdivision.whatever". However, in the treemap diagrams on the dashboard all the packages are displayed as "src/main/java/com/ourdomain/someapplication/subdivision/whatever". As you can see in the attached screenshot, it makes the package names harder to read and the project becomes harder to navigate.

I am sure this is due to a faulty configuration on our part, but is it something to do with Sonar or Maven or Jenkins? Or something else?

[image: sonarqube treemap screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since SonarQube 4.2, all language analysers behave the same way and so indeed the path of all source files is relative to the project root directory. I known this might sound like a regression in your case.

Comment: So, sadly, this is "working as intended", then? It's a logical change on your part, so I can definitely see how it makes sense. It's just sad that it affects the display so much.

Is there any configuration I can do so that we can just hide an irrelevant part of the source path (in our case "src/main"java") in the TreeMap display of the package names? Or maybe it can be added as a change request for future versions?

Btw, sorry if this behaviour already has been changed in the newer versions of SonarQube. We will upgrade soon(tm)...